# Click Image Changes BG Image of Parent Div & Loads Div 5 Secs Later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a video player mockup for a friends website and need a bit of help with the jquery/javascript

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="video">
     <div id="notification"><span>lorem ipsum.</span></div>
     <img id="loading" src="loading.gif" />
     <img id="play" src="playbutton.png" style="width: 100%" />
</div>
```

`#video` has the background of what looks like a video player, so what I want to do is

1. when the use clicks on `#play` it will change the background image from having an image to black a black screen
2. then I would like `#loading` to appear
3. then 5 seconds later I want `#notification` to appear

how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the style 'display:none' to the elements you want hidden.

And attach an onclick handler to the #play div which you can do with the jQuery function `.on`

For Example:

```
$('#play').on('click',function() {
    //remove image
    $('#play').hide();

    //display loading panel
    $('#loading').css('display','block');

    setTimeout(function(){
        //display notification
        $('#notification').css('display','block');
    }, 5000);
}
```

The `setTimeout` function will give you the delay.